# how to draw pattern programmatically in android unit test?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-espresso

I want to develop unit test for my project android and I have a problem , my App has lock screen with custom pattern and I want to develop in test site , but the problem is how can draw nodes pattern lock screen?